# Throttling of messages on consumer side

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am beginner level at kafka and have developed consumer for kafka messages which looks good right now.
Though there is a requirement came along while testing of consumer that may be some throttling of messages will be needed at consumer side.

The consumer (.net core, using confluent), after receiving messages, calls api and api processes the message. As part this process, It has few number of read and write to database.
The scenario is, Consumer may receive millions or atleast few thousand of messages daily. This makes load on DB side as part of processing.

So I am thinking to put some throttling on receiving messages on kafka consumer so the DB will not be overloaded. I have checked the option for poll but seems its not all that I want. 
For example, within 10 minutes, consumer can receive 100k messages only. Something like that.

Could anybody please suggest how to implement throttling of messages on kafka consumer or is there any better way that this can be handled?

Answer (score 0):

I investigated more and come to know from expert that "throttling on consumer side is not easy to implement, since kafka consumer is implemented in such way to read and process messages as soon as they are available in kafka topic. So, speed is a benefit in kafka world :)"

Seems I can not do much at kafka consumer side. I am thinking to see on the other side and may be  separating reads (to replica) and writes to the database can help.

Comment: It's possible now - you can pause the consumer and resume after you committed the messages to the DB
https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/Consumer.html#pause(java.util.Collection)